# nfq_create_queue():Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: iptables, recv, netfilter

Got the error 'Resource temporarily unavailable' when I tried to create multiple nf_queues in my application.  I could not find any documentation for this error.

I am trying to implement a multi-threaded application with NFQUEUEs.  I opened the library and binded to AF_INET in the main thread and trying to create multiple NFQUEUEs.  It is successfully creating 5 queues and the next nfq_create_queue returns 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.

I also tried with sleep(1); between calling nfq_create_queue() but got the same error.

global variables :

```
struct nfq_handle *h;
int fd;
```

main thread:

```
h = nfq_open();
nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET)
nfq_bind_pf(h, AF_INET)
qh = nfq_create_queue(h,  NFQ_NUMBER_START_IPv4 + self_index, &cb_ip4, NULL);
nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff);
nfq_set_queue_maxlen(qh, NFQ_LENGTH);
fd = nfq_fd(h);
nfnl_rcvbufsiz(nfq_nfnlh(h), NFQLENGTH * BUFSIZE);
```

worker threads:

```
qh = nfq_create_queue(h,  NFQ_NUMBER_START_IPv4 + self_index, &cb_ip4, NULL);
nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff)
nfq_set_queue_maxlen(qh, NFQ_LENGTH);
```

Comment: nfq is single threaded

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you please explain it further?  All the queues were properly created when I called nfq_create_queue() from the same thread.  So, now can I recv() from multiple threads with the single fd?  I know that POSIX defined recv() is thread-safe.  Is it the same with NFQUEUEs?